# Perl: Matching columns from two different files

Tags: perl, bigdata

(Note: Column headers are there for readability and are not in the actual files)

#### File 1

```
COLUMN1         COLUMN2   COLUMN3
AG_446337835.1  example1  grgsdt
AG_448352465.1  example2  190197
AG_449465753.1  example3  h837h8
AG_449366462.1  example4  d34tw4
AG_444725037.1  example5  f45ge4
AG_441227463.1  example6  f3fw4t
AG_449986090.1  example7  gft7r4
AG_445666926.1  example8  4vsr55
AG_441004541.1  example9  fh893b
AG_444837264.1  example0  k3883d
```

#### File 2

```
COLUMN1  COLUMN2
grgsdt   AAHG
h837h8   JUJN
190197   POKJ
f45ge4   DFRF
gft7r4   NNHN
d34tw4
fh893b  YUNIP
k3883d  YUNIP
f3fw4t  YUNIP
190197  YUNIP
4vsr55  GHGF
```

#### Desired Output file

```
COLUMN1         COLUMN2   COLUMN3 COLUMN4 (formerly column2 from file2)
AG_446337835.1  example1  grgsdt  AAHG 
AG_448352465.1  example2  190197  POKJ  YUNIP
AG_449465753.1  example3  h837h8  JUJN
AG_449366462.1  example4  d34tw4  
AG_444725037.1  example5  f45ge4  DFRF
AG_441227463.1  example6  f3fw4t  YUNIP
AG_449986090.1  example7  gft7r4  NNHN
AG_445666926.1  example8  4vsr55  GHGF
AG_441004541.1  example9  fh893b  YUNIP
AG_444837264.1  example0  k3883d  YUNIP
```

I am barely familiar with Perl (or programming general) and I was wondering if you would mind advising me with this problem.

Essentially, Column 3 in file1 corresponds to Column 1 in File2.

I want to take each line in file1, read column 3 of that line, search file2 for a matching entry, if a matching entry exists print the line from file1 with an extra column from file 2 to a new file (as seen in the example output).

The file sizes are

File1: 2GB

File2: 718MB

This script will be run off a machine with 250GB of ram so memory is not an issue.

This is what I have so far

```
#!/usr/bin/perl ;
#use warnings;

use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);
use experimental 'smartmatch';
#Variable to store inputted text file data
my $db ;
my $db2 ;




#Open and read File one into memory
open FPIN, "file1.txt" or die "Could not open";
my @file1 = <FPIN> ;
close FPIN;

#Open and read file two into memory
open FPIN, "file2.tab" or die "Could not open";
my @file2 = <FPIN> ;
close FPIN ;




foreach (@file2)
  {
    if (/(^\w+)\t(.+)/)
      { 
        split /\t/, $2; 
        $db2->{$1}->{"geneName"} = $1 ;
        $db2->{$1}->{"protein"} = $2 ;
      }             

  }

foreach (@file1)
    {
      #if line begins with any word character tab and anything
      if (/(^\w+.\d+)\t(.+)/)
        { 
            my @fields = split /\t/, $2;
            my $refSeqID = $1;

           #assign the data in the array to variables
            my ($geneSymbol, $geneName) = @fields[0, 1];

          #Create database data structure and fill it with the info
            $db->{$2}->{"refSeqID"} = $refSeqID ;
            $db->{$2}->{"geneSymbol"} = $geneSymbol ;
            $db->{$2}->{"geneName"} = $geneName ;

       }
   }         

foreach my $id (sort keys %{$db2}) 
  {
    if ( exists $db->{$id} )
      {   
        print $db2->{$id}."\t".$db->{$id}->{$geneSymbol}."\t".$db->{$id}-> 
        {$refSeqID}."\t".$db2->{$id}->{$protein}."\n";
      }

  }
```

I seem to be able to read both files into memory correctly.
However I have been completely unable to compare the files to each other and I am dumbstruck on how to approach it.

Actually printing it will be another issue I need to tackle.

Comment: Are the column headings part of the file?

Comment: No I just added those in for readability. I will edit that information in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do as you ask

It starts by reading `file2.txt` and building a hash `%f2` that relates the value of the first column to the value of the second

Thereafter it's just a matter of reading through `file1.txt`, splitting it into fields, and adding a further field obtained by accessing the hash using the value of the third field

I've used `autodie` to save the trouble of handling errors in the `open` calls. Otherwise everything is standard

#### Update

I've just noticed that a column 1 value may be repeated in `file2.txt`, so I've changed the code to make each key of the hash correspond to an *array* of values. All the values in the array appear, space-separated, in column 4 of the output

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use autodie;

my %f2;

{
    open my $fh, '<', 'file2.txt';
    while ( <$fh> ) {
        my ($key, $val) = split;
        $f2{$key} //= [];
        push @{ $f2{$key} }, $val if $val;
    }
}

open my $fh, '<', 'file1.txt';

while ( <$fh> ) {
    my @line = split;
    my $c4 =  $f2{$line[2]};
    push @line, $c4 ? join(' ', @$c4) : '';
    local $" = "\t";
    print "@line\n";
}
```

#### output

```
AG_446337835.1  example1    grgsdt  AAHG
AG_448352465.1  example2    190197  POKJ YUNIP
AG_449465753.1  example3    h837h8  JUJN
AG_449366462.1  example4    d34tw4  
AG_444725037.1  example5    f45ge4  DFRF
AG_441227463.1  example6    f3fw4t  YUNIP
AG_449986090.1  example7    gft7r4  NNHN
AG_445666926.1  example8    4vsr55  GHGF
AG_441004541.1  example9    fh893b  YUNIP
AG_444837264.1  example0    k3883d  YUNIP
```

Comment: It worked. I cant begin to thank you enough but I will start anyway.                       Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This one makes a [left join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_join). The key idea is to use `geneName` as a key in a hash.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data = ();

open $a, "file1";
while (<$a>) {
    chomp;
    my @c = split;
    $data{$c[2]} = [$c[0], $c[1], $c[2]];
}

open $b, "file2";
while (<$b>) {
    chomp;
    my @c = split;
    push @{$data{$c[0]}}, exists $c[1] ? $c[1] : "";
}

print map { "@{$_}\n" } values %data;
```

Comment: It would help if you explained why you think a "left join" is better.

Comment: I was wrong. You do also a left join. Both answers are the same.